# ListView - Make Button onClick event add value to EditText on the same row

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a ListView that populates the app with an EditText and a Button on each line.

I've added an onClick event to the Buttons, which adds +1 to the EditText's value. It works fine, except that every button only adds to the first EditText.

How can I capture which Button was pressed, in order to add +1 to the respective EditText (on the same Button line)?

Here's what I have so far:

**row_layout_2.xml**

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_plus"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="addone"
         />
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
public void addone(View v){

    int numtest = 1;

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);

    int numtemp = Integer.parseInt(t.getText().toString());

    int sum_numbers = numtest + numtemp;

    String final_sum = String.valueOf(sum_numbers);

    t.setText(final_sum);
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.serveira.fluxoparagem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

//The following adapter makes it possible for me to put both strings
// into different columns.

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] products;
    private String[] prices;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] products, String[] prices) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.products = products;
        this.prices = prices;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_2, parent, false);
        TextView column1 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView column2 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        column1.setText(products[position]);
        column2.setText(prices[position]);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add your onClick method on your listview adapter.

Comment: can you add your adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put onClick method inside your getView method inside adapter as below

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_2, parent, false);
    final TextView column1 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView column2 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button plus1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button_plus);

    column1.setText(products[position]);
    column2.setText(prices[position]);

    plus1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                products[position]++;
                column1.setText(products[position]);
            }
        });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you to do like this in you adapter class.

```
 holder.(findViewById(R.id.button_plus)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
              //  holder.(findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1))


    int numtemp = Integer.parseInt( holder.(findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1)).getText().toString());

    int sum_numbers = numtest + numtemp;

    String final_sum = String.valueOf(sum_numbers);

     holder.(findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1)).setText(final_sum);    
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! What would the `holder` be? I tried replacing it with `R` and `View`, but none of them worked. I will edit my  question and provide my `CustomAdapter`